# Autofac - resolving less specific covariant implementations

Tags: c#, autofac, covariance

I am using Autofac. Let's say I have an covariant interface

```
interface IOptionFactory<out T> where T : IOption
```

and specific implementations

```
class Option1Factory : IOptionFactory<Option1>
class Option2Factory : IOptionFactory<Option2>
```

I register them as

```
container.RegisterType<Option1Factory>.As<IOptionFactory<Option1>>();
container.RegisterType<Option2Factory>.As<IOptionFactory<Option2>>();
```

Is there a way, how to resolve all implementations of IOptionFactory? Because this is covariant, this should be legal in C# (am I right?). Something like:

```
var factories = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IOptionFactory<IOption>>>();
```

Comment: As far as I remember, Autofac only supports contravaiance. Also, what you are doing doesn't make a huge amount of sense to me here. What would you even do with your list of factories? You would end up with some really odd code there.

Comment: I have a class Item, which contains IOption (each presents a different strategy for some computation, not important here). And for each Item, the user can select which IOption it should contain. And because the architecture is extensible by plugins, I need to offer a selection of all available IOption to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to wrap your code in a `Reporting` class with a private `IEnumerable` property of `IOptionFactory<IOption>`.

```
private class Reporting
{
    private IEnumerable<IOptionFactory<IOption>> _allOptionsFactories;

    public Reporting(IEnumerable<IOptionFactory<IOption>> allOptionsFactories)
    {
        if (allOptionsFactories == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter:" + nameof(allOptionsFactories));
        }
        this._allOptionsFactories = allOptionsFactories;
    }

    public void Report()
    {
        foreach (var optionsFactories in _allOptionsFactories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(optionsFactories.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can register and use them with:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PassingParametersToRegister_NamedParameter()
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<IOption1Factory1<SomeOption>>().As<IOptionFactory<IOption>>();
    builder.RegisterType<IOption1Factory2<SomeOption>>().As<IOptionFactory<IOption>>();
    builder.RegisterType<Reporting>();

    using (var container = builder.Build())
    {
        container.Resolve<Reporting>().Report();
    }

    //OUTPUT:

    //Enumerations + IOption1Factory1`1[Enumerations + SomeOption]
    //Enumerations + IOption1Factory2`1[Enumerations + SomeOption]
}
```

Here is the entire code in my [github](https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/DependencyInjectionAutofac/blob/master/DependencyInjectionWithAutofac/Section4%20-%20Implicit%20Relationship%20Types/GenericEnumerations.cs)

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. The allOptionFactories returns empty enumerable. But I noticed, that I can register the factories as the base generic definition
`builder.RegisterType<Option1Factory>().AsSelf().As<IOptionFactory<IOption>>();`
and then it works. Is there a way, how to resolve it automatically using Autofac, or do I need to register them also as the base type? 
And also, what is the advantage of using the Factories, instead of injecting the list itself?

Comment: Interesting... I've managed to build working sample: https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/DependencyInjectionAutofac/blob/master/DependencyInjectionWithAutofac/Section5%20-%20Implicit%20Relationship%20Types/Enumerations.cs, Without the `AsSelf()`.

Comment: And also, what is the advantage of using the Factories, instead of injecting the list itself? I think you better post it as a new question - you will get much better answer

Comment: The example is not the same as the described problem. The classes are not generic! The ILog would need to be something as `interface ILog<out T> where T : IReport`

Comment: Hey @FilipMestanek, I've updated an example as the described problem :) https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/DependencyInjectionAutofac/blob/master/DependencyInjectionWithAutofac/Section5%20-%20Implicit%20Relationship%20Types/GenericEnumerations.cs Let me know please if you still has any issue

Comment: Yeah, this example works. The only not-so-nice thing is, that I have to register the classes as the base type IOptionFactory<IOption>, that Autofac doesn't to this automatically by itself. Maybe there can be something like ContravariantRegistrationSource for this.

Comment: Glad I could help, what do you mean by itself?

Comment: I would expect to register RegisterType<Option1Factory>.As<IOptionFactory<Option1>> and then be able to resolve it as Resolve<IOptionFactory<IOption>>, because it is covariant [and therefore IOptionFactory<Option1> can be assigned to IOptionFactory<IOption>]

Comment: `As<IOptionFactory<Option1>>` - Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think its bad idea to register the `As` part with `Option1`, because `Option1` is implementation not abstraction.